# ".csv" download by clicking on the download button in shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny

I want the 'dat' data frame to download as dat.csv file from shiny UI.
 Can anyone help me with the code?

```
library(shiny)
library(ECharts2Shiny)

dat <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 4, 6))
names(dat) <- c("Type-A", "Type-B")
row.names(dat) <- c("Time-1", "Time-2", "Time-3")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download CSV
Report', style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 230px;color:
black;")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler({
        filename = function() {
            paste('dat', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
        }
        content = function(file) {
            csv_write <- dat
            write.csv(csv_write,row.names=FALSE, na="")
        }
    })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: While clicking on the "Download CSV Report" button a pop window appears and asked us to save the file. But while saving the file, I have no option to choose from  "Save as" drop down. Only, by default it saves as R file.

Comment: You seem to forget the part where you write the file name with `file = filename` inside `write.csv`, does this solve it?

Comment: Getting :                                                                                                     
        Error in output$downloadData <- downloadHandler({ : 
        object 'output' not found
        > })
        Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
        > shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
        Error in shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) : object 'server' not found

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your code correctly. You also have a `,` unwanted, please try to fix your example. Just to create your problem.